# How to persist the LiveConnectSession in LiveSDK-iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, live-sdk, onedrive

After I finished the Microsoft Live oAuth, the `LiveConnectSession` is not nil and everything is working. But after I restart the simulator or device, the `LiveConnectClient`'s `LiveConnectSession` is `nil`.

How do I persist the `LiveConnectSession` to keychain so I can make API request without the `LiveConnectSession` deallocating? If I only have to persist the access token, everything will be easy but the LiveSDK for iOS is using this `LiveConnectSession` object.

Comment: Please include the desired behaviour and some code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In the LiveSDK, it will save the session by sdk itself, see this file `LiveAuthStorage.m`. If you want to persist the `LiveConnectSession` in LiveSDK-iOS, just give the `wl.offline_access` scope when login.